# How to disable re-compilation for dependent module?

Tags: scala, sbt

There is a sbt-project with the following modules:

```
val core: Project = ...

val moduleA: Project = project.settings(...)
                              .dependsOn(core)

var root: Project = Project(
   id = "...",
   settings = ...,
   base = file(".")).aggregate(moduleA)
```

The `core` module has a lot of classes. The `modlueA` is a web-module which can be deployed in the container (in jetty for example).
I can deploy and run that module with the following command:

```
sbt: > project moduleA
sbt: > container:start
```

But when I use `container:start` then the `core` module is recompiled too. And it takes a lot of time.

How can I disable re-compilation of the `core` module. Because if there are changes in the `moduleA` but there aren't changes in the `core` module then I don't want to compile the `core`.